# Concatenate nested JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to concatenate nested JSON in SQL, how to do that.

Please help me out with this.

Example: **I have JSON Like below**.

```
    [
  {
    "Name": "Cards",
    "Value": [
      "Pack of 24 Dare Cards"
    ],
    "SourceSpecified": false,
    "Any": []
  },
  {
    "Name": "Boppers and Shot Glasses",
    "Value": [
      "12 Willy Shot Glass and 12 Hen Boppers"
    ],
    "SourceSpecified": false,
    "Any": []
  }
]
```

I want **Out Put:**

```
Pack of 24 Dare Cards-12 Willy Shot Glass and 12 Hen Boppers
```

Comment: Will Value only contain one element?

Comment: Yes only one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one I achieved with creating a scalar-valued function to populate concatenated value.

```
Create FUNCTION  [dbo].[test] 
(
    @VariationData nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
                          Declare @val nvarchar(max)
                          select @val = COALESCE(@val+', ','')+ Value from  OPENJSON(@VariationData)
                          With ([Value] NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.Value[0]') 
                          return @val

END
```

Call function with nested JSON value i.e

```
Select  [dbo].[test] (@JSON);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If Value always contains one element

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = '    [
  {
    "Name": "Cards",
    "Value": [
      "Pack of 24 Dare Cards"
    ],
    "SourceSpecified": false,
    "Any": []
  },
  {
    "Name": "Boppers and Shot Glasses",
    "Value": [
      "12 Willy Shot Glass and 12 Hen Boppers"
    ],
    "SourceSpecified": false,
    "Any": []
  }
]'

SELECT STRING_AGG(Val, '-')
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
WITH (Val NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Value[0]')
```

Support of multiple *value*s is also easy.

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(Val, '-')
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
WITH (VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Value' AS JSON)
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(VALUE) WITH (Val NVARCHAR(MAX) '$')
```

Comment: 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: STRING_AGG need SqlServer 2017 as min version

Comment: You tagged sql-server-2017.

Comment: Sorry mine is sql server 2016

Comment: There are plenty of string join solutions prior SQL Server 2017. Just search it. I think your core question is json instead of string join.

Comment: Link - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/